# Rock, Paper, Scissors in javascript using an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having trouble writing code for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using javascript. I know its a common topic on here but I'm just starting out and couldn't find anything specifically with the use of arrays in the way I am trying to use it. I used an array to make the computer randomly generate a number, then I want it to prompt the user to input a number. Here is where I started:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var theRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
   deptArray = new Array(3);
deptArray[0] = "No Pick";
deptArray[1] = "Rock";
deptArray[2] = "Paper";
deptArray[3] = "Scissors";
     document.write("Your opponent chose" + deptArray[deptNo]);
   document.write("<br>");
   var myGuess = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your guess 1-Rock 2-Paper 3-Scissors"));
   if (theRanNum == myGuess)
      {
       document.write("Tie");
  }
   else
      {
       if (theRanNum = 1) and (myGuess = 2)
```

I am not exactly sure if I should go about making the IF statements the way I started, or even if my code so far is right. The white screen has been my best friend so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The very last line needs to be `if (theRanNum == 1 && myGuess == 2) { ... }`, and then you need close your earlier braces.

Comment: Is this all your code? Cause this will throw an error at its current state.

Comment: `deptArray[deptNo]` should be `deptArray[theRanNum]`. And I'm not sure how much fun the game will be if you tell the user what the computer has picked before they have their turn...

Comment: OK, thanks Grim ill try that out. And no this isn't all the code I just didn't feel it was needed to put all the IF statements in as I was sure they were wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   var theRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
   deptArray = [];
   deptArray.push("Rock");
   deptArray.push("Paper");
   deptArray.push("Scissors");
   var myGuess = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your guess 1-Rock 2-Paper 3-Scissors:"));
   if (myGuess > 0 && myGuess < 4) {
      document.write("You chose: " + deptArray[myGuess]);
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("PC chose: " + deptArray[1]);
      if (theRanNum == myGuess) {
           document.write("Tie");
      } else {
          if (theRanNum == 1 && myGuess == 2)
            document.write("You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 1 && myGuess == 3)
            document.write("You lose!");
          else if (theRanNum == 2 && myGuess == 1)
            document.write("You lose!");
          else if (theRanNum == 2 && myGuess == 3)
            document.write("You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 3 && myGuess == 1)
            document.write("You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 3 && myGuess == 2)
            document.write("You lose!");
      }
   } else {
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("You chose a wrong number!");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really know what the "deptArray.push" does, and the user input numbers are off for me but it cleared some stuff up so ill test around some more, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, Prelite's code pretty much worked I just had to change `document.write("PC chose: " + deptArray[1]);` into `document.write("PC chose: " + deptArray[theRanNum]);` and I switched up the array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var theRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
   deptArray = new Array(3);
deptArray[0] = "No Pick";
deptArray[1] = "Rock";
deptArray[2] = "Paper";
deptArray[3] = "Scissors";
   var myGuess = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your guess 1-Rock 2-Paper 3-Scissors:"));
   if (myGuess > 0 && myGuess < 4) {
      document.write("You chose " + deptArray[myGuess]);
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("PC chose " + deptArray[theRanNum]);
      if (theRanNum == myGuess) {
           document.write(": Tie");
       } else {
          if (theRanNum == 1 && myGuess == 2)
            document.write(": You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 1 && myGuess == 3)
            document.write(": You lose!");
          else if (theRanNum == 2 && myGuess == 1)
            document.write(": You lose!");
          else if (theRanNum == 2 && myGuess == 3)
            document.write(": You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 3 && myGuess == 1)
            document.write(": You win!");
          else if (theRanNum == 3 && myGuess == 2)
            document.write(": You lose!");
      }
   } else {
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("You chose a wrong number!");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: You could have voted for my post which helped you solve your problem Tstanley12, but maybe you did not get Stackoverflow's spirit, like you did not understand the push.

Comment: I'm sorry? I legit credited you in my answer, I just said I changed some stuff to work for me cause I'm still in school and I'm not gonna use stuff I haven't learned about yet. I thanked and credited you and if that's not good 'spirits' then sorry...